# Help me fixing IE 7 Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I have setup Ad Gallery (Jquery based gallery plugin, see http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/ ) on a website I'm developing. Everything works just fine in recent browsers.. the only problem is with IE7 which throws a JS error and stops executing the script.

I don't have access to debugging utils for IE7 so I can't really investigate into the problem.

Comment: Posting the error would help.

Comment: We are not going to debug your code for you.  Why can't you use IE7's debug utils?  Also, if you posted the JS error you got, we may be able to do something.

Comment: [IE Dev Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en) and [Web Dev Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/) are free debugging utilities for IE. An Express version of VS is another free alternative, if a bit of overkill.

Comment: Hitting F12 in IE7 doesn't popup up the build in 'developer tools'? AFAIK it does in IE8 and IE9. If you have IE9 and you load that developer tools, then you can switch there the 'browser mode' to IE7.

Comment: @NT3RP Here is the error msg I got after switching browser mode to IE7  
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
galleria, line 1806 character 7

Comment: @Rocket 'we may be able to do something'  
We _are_ able to do something with the info he provided. Upvoting, don't see why he would deserve downvotes.

Comment: Picture of the error is at http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2360/galleria.png I can't run IE7 debug tools as I'm running it under IETester.

Comment: @TweeZz: Posting the error displayed is part of asking a good question.  'It doesn't work, fix it!' is *not* a good question.  We should not have to figure out the error, it should be in the question.

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with and the error you're getting, not a link to your site.  Just linking to your site looks like an attempt to drive traffic.

Comment: @Fabio: I see you're using IETester, doesn't that have DebugBar built in?

Comment: Come on guys. As TweeZz showed you in his answer, you would have had anything needed to provide an answer. In my opinion describing a javascript error like this one is quite pointless as, given a correct debugging/development IE setup, finding and fixing such an issue is a matter of a couple of minutes, as TweeZz demonstrated. I'm a Linux users and develop for standard compliant browsers so I really lack experience debugging on IE. That's why I asked for help here.

Comment: To the admins who edited my question removing the link.. the linked website is clearly a development space.. I don't really see a reason why I would like to drive traffic to an antique store website written in Italian and clearly under development from Stackoverflow.. come on.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would make people go to your site to download your code when you can post code and a description here.  Put enough information *in your question* so that people can answer it, not somewhere else.  If your in-development site goes down or changes then your question becomes pointless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found why. Here's the block of js where it crashes:

```
Drupal.behaviors.ad_gallery = {
    attach: function(context) {
      //alert(Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.style);
      var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
        animation_speed: parseInt(Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.animation_speed),
        display_next_and_prev: Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.display_next_and_prev,
        display_back_and_forward: Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.display_back_and_forward,
        slideshow: {
          enable: Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.ss_enable,
          autostart: Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.ss_autostart,
        }
      });
...
```

Do you have control over this piece of js code? I suspect the issue is in the line where 'autostart' is set. Are you able to remove that comma at the end?

Change:

```
autostart: Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.ss_autostart,
```

to:

```
autostart: Drupal.settings.ad_gallery.ss_autostart
```

Comment: Stupid IE not liking trailing commas, and not telling me *that's* the problem.

Comment: hehe :)  Somehow it told me that it was the problem :)

Comment: Thank you TweeZz.. the suggested change fixed it.

Comment: Awesome! Similar problem. Firefox ignores a trailing comma but IE freaking out. When I read trailing comma, sure enough I had one. Doh!